# Submit and disable all buttons in an ng-repeat without adding a new property on the scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, form-submit

I have a list of items where each item is clickable and should trigger the `submit(id)` function. I would like to disable all items (buttons) when one of them is clicked.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button ng-click="submit(item.id)">Submit</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I could define `$scope.submitted` variable in a controller and then set `ng-disabled="submitted"` in my view. I could also wrap it into a `<form>` and use `frm.$submitted`. Well... I would like to define everything inside view.

I search for an elegant solution where a don't have to define a `$scope` variable to achieve this. What do you propose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to define a property in the controller, and assuming that `submit` function never fails to submit. You could utilize the `items` array itself, by adding a property when click happens and after submit function is run.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button ng-click="submit(item.id); items.submitted=true" 
                ng-disabled="items.submitted">Submit</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With this you are adding a property in the array `items` (so that it is available across child scopes of ng-repeat as well as items is set on its parent scope) so essentially you are not defining a new scope variable for this.

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
   $scope.items = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button ng-click="submit(item.id); items.submitted=true" 
                ng-disabled="items.submitted">Submit</button>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ;) haha.. guessed thats what you may have wanted.. :)